# Ubuntu 19.04 - connectivity checking

Tags: networking, 19.04

I have updated to 19.04. from 18.04 LTS (first to 18.10 then 19.04)

I used to have a question mark in my WIFI sign at the right corner with 18.04. I turned connectivity checking off in privacy settings and it disappeared.

Now the question mark is there again with 19.04 and i have to turn on and off connectivity checking whenever i log in.

any ideas?

[image: question mark]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the 'question mark' you mention ?

Comment: Preferably [edit] your post, then add the images.

Comment: i have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark in wifi shows no internet access from a given network.
Does the question mark always appear when you log in?

Comment: i  do have internet access, and it works just fine.  And yes, it does always appear. It has been an issue before, but i managed to solve by turning off connectivity checking in privacy settings. Now it is turned off, but the question mark is still there.